# MYSQL INSERT - "0 rows inserted". Any suggestions why is that?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO fields (id_region, id_fields_info, subsidy_dka, id_rents_dka, type_uses, id_rented_from, id_categories, id_farmer, id_season) 
SELECT 
    regions.id,
        fields_info.id ,
        120,
    rents_dka.rent_dka, 
        "собствена",
    rented_froms.id, 
        categories.id_category, 
        farmers.id, 
        seasons.id

FROM regions, fields_info, rents_dka, rented_froms, categories, farmers,
    seasons
WHERE 
        region = "Азмък" AND
        field_num = 2222 AND
        rent_dka = 60 AND
        name = "Десислав" AND
        id_category = 3 AND
        name = "Десислав" AND
        season = "2012-2013"
```

So I have these tables:

```
regions,
fields_info,
rents_dka, 
rented_froms, 
categories, 
farmers, 
seasons
```

and they are filled with some data.
I've made a form where the user fills the fields with data from these tables, that I've mentioned, and when the submit button is clicked I want to fill table FIELDS in MYSQL with ID's which I get from the data, the user had entered.

Comment: did you try to make the SELECT alone, to see if it gets any records ?

Comment: You should try to improve the quality of your question if you really expect someone to help you.

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you give the table definitions for all the tables. Even then, it is probably too extensive, and you should try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I've explained it as short as I could.. to get the idea

Comment: Do the tables relate to one another in some way?

Comment: From main table "FIELDS" to others with FK

Answer (score 2):

to spot the problem, I'd proceed as follow:

- execute an insert without cyrillic
- remove all the and
- make a default insert with default values

if you get "0 rows inserted" it means that the syntax is correct, but the where clause fails to find any matching entry. I suspect the problem is the AND with the cyrillic. Remove the ANDs until the query finds some entries

Answer (score 0):

I got this case when i tried to insert into a table having a column unique and my SQL had the keyword `IGNORE` in it :

The query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO users SET `user_id` = 7321, `name`= 'test_name', `phone` = '+188888888';
```

If the query didn't have `IGNORE`, it would throw an error (because the column `user_id` was set unique and I already had a row with the same `user_id`) but due to `IGNORE` keyword it just ignores the query and hence results in 0 rows inserted.

Note: I know the question asked doesn't has `IGNORE` key in the query, but might help someone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't seem to be the case in the code snippet provided in the question.

Comment: @shaedrich Yeah that's why I put the note, some might run into this scenario, in that case it can be helpful!